# eclipse with new aws java web project, upgrade jar version

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, but I can't find similar question on google or stackoverflow.

I'm using eclipse (luna), and I have this plugin from amazon, `aws toolkit`. When I create a project by clicking 'new aws web project', a new project will be created, and inside the `aws sdk for java`, some of the jar files have a version which is not I want, for example, `spring-core-3.0.7.jar`.

I tried convert this project to maven project and include dependency with latest `spring-webmvc 4.x`, but is seems two packages have conflict with each other. ref:

[why .NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry.addConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438807/why-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-core-convert-converter-converterregi)

[Two Maven Dependency for latest and old version conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823106/two-maven-dependency-for-latest-and-old-version-conflicts)

[Spring MVC - Why the NoSuchMethodError exception when deploying context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754857/spring-mvc-why-the-nosuchmethoderror-exception-when-deploying-context)

I tried to delete or upgrade the jar from `aws sdk for java`, but I can't find a way to delete it or upgrade it.

Then, I tried to create a normal java web project, convert to maven project and include the `aws-java-sdk-core` from maven repository, but after that I can't use the `deploy to elastic beanstalk` function.

Actually, I just want to create a project which let me use the latest spring framework, and also able to deploy to aws elastic beanstalk.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow steps:

1. create aws java web project
2. convert to maven project
3. delete aws java sdk package
4. add necessary jar using maven pom.xml
5. upload to aws elastic beanstalk

it works.

Comment: Would you have any guides on how to actually go about these steps?